# asp.net dynamic controls values

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, textbox

I am trying to create a poll system that will ask the users for the number of options they would like to add from a dropdownlist.

Then when the user choose a number i would like to add text-boxes for those numbers and finally use asp.net to iterate through the text-boxes and add their values in the database.

Example:

> 1. User chooses to add 5 options.
> 2. I use Jquery to to append 5 inputs to the form.
> 3. User adds their values.
> 4. I iterate through the text-boxes and execute a void based on these
>      values.

i am able to do the first 3 steps but i am stuck on the 4th step. To solve it i tried to use a loop:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in form1.Controls) 
{
   Response.Write(tb.Text);
}
```

but that throws an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

how can i iterate throw the text-boxes?

thanks

Comment: Umm... You wrote only 4 steps...

Comment: @Blachshma - My mistake, question updated.

Comment: Please add the code you have until now, and explain what exactly is your problem..

Comment: You have a bit of a disconnect here. You imply that you want to create the controls client side with jQuery but want to iterate through them with asp.net which is a server side technology. Those two approaches won't play nicely with one another.

Comment: @andleer - this step is not essential, i can use asp.net instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any static content is represented by a LiteralControl, which is why you experience that.  A real easy way is to use LINQ:

```
var ctls = form1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
foreach (var ctl in ctls) { .. )
```

Or check the type as you loop through the controls to make sure it's a textbox first:

```
foreach (Control tb in form1.Controls) 
{
   if (tb is TextBox)
      Response.Write(((TextBox)tb).Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, both solutions works fine, i was wondering though if one solution is better?

Comment: I like LINQ as it keeps it concise.  The latter might be sliiiightly more efficient, as the first option loops through all controls, does the type check, returns a collection, and then you can foreach through it.  The latter does all of that in one operation.  But I don't really think the performance gain is that huge...

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer seems a solid one. Another option that comes to mind at first sight is:

- Declare a function...
- Declare a simple array or even a string in js
- Iterate from client side your inputs
- And for each iteration you should be saving the value in that array or concatenating the value.

The array then can be saved as a string in some asp hiddenfield in order to do your server-side stuff.

Best regards.

Comment: This would definitely work, but i am trying to combine the text-boxes with uploads, and i cannot retrieve the file path through JavaScript. Thanks